# Can't upgrade from windows 8 to windows 8.1 from windows store

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've just bought Dell 15 7537 with Windows 8. It had single partition while purchasing. So, I created three more partitions. I've also installed every updates from Windows Update. But whenever I tried to  "Update to Windows 8.1" from Windows Store.

```
1) The files are downloaded
2) Every steps before reboot goes successful
```

The Setup couldn't continue and the welcome screen appears with the message

```
**Couldn't update to Windows 8.1**
Sorry, we couldn't complete the update to Windows 8.1. We've restored your previous version of Windows to this PC.
0x80073B92 - 0x20009
```

I tried following steps, as suggested in many forums, multiple times. Even though they ended with the same message

```
1) Downloaded all updates, drivers and apps
2) Removed cache using wsreset.exe
3) Checked if multiple HDD exists (single 1TB HDD exists)
4) Synced Licenses
5) Removed external HDD, keyboards and other stuff
6) Changed to clean boot
5) and other stuffs
```

I would be thankful if someone help me getting solution for this error. Why is this error recurring every time?

Comment: 0x80073B92 = ERROR_AMBIGUOUS_SYSTEM_DEVICE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are one of two methods that should work for you.  The first method is the following:

> Method 1:
>
> If you connected a second drive or any external drive to your PC (a
>   SSD or HDD) the upgrade will fail if the second (original) drive is
>   not disconnected. Just remove the secondary drive and all external
>   drive, reboot and try installing the Windows 8.1 update.

The second method is the following:

> Method 2:
>
> If you do not have any external drive connected to your PC, boot the
>   computer in a clean boot state and then try to install and check.
>   Booting the computer in a clean boot state uses a minimal set of
>   drivers and start-up programs. A clean boot helps eliminate software
>   conflicts.  You can refer to this article for more information:

[Source](http://tipsandtricksforum.com/thread-154.html)

In order to do a clean boot you should do the following:

> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. Or, if you are using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the
>      screen, and then click Search.
> 2. Type msconfig in the search box, and then tap or click msconfig.
> 3. On the Services tab of the System Configuration dialog box, tap or click to select the Hide all Microsoft services check box, and then
>      tap or click Disable all.
> 4. On the Startup tab of the System Configuration dialog box, tap or click Open Task Manager.
> 5. On the Startup tab in Task Manager, for each startup item, select the item and then click Disable.
> 6. Close Task Manager.
> 7. On the Startup tab of the System Configuration dialog box, tap or click OK, and then restart the computer.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135)

Comment: I've tried all options including Clean boot option. This resulted the same message time and again.